# Getting the first element of a list in Puppeteer (await problem)

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

This works :

```
await configPage.goto('http://....', {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'} );
await configPage.waitForTimeout(2000);
let news = await configPage.$$("article.news");
await configPage.waitForTimeout(2000);
let firstNews = news[0];
await configPage.waitForTimeout(2000);
let content = await firstNews.$eval('div.news-body', s => { return s.textContent.trim(); });
console.log(content);
```

But without the waitForTimeout, it doesn't :

```
await configPage.goto('http://....', {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'} );
let news = await configPage.$$("article.news");
let firstNews = news[0];
let content = await firstNews.$eval('div.news-body', s => { return s.textContent.trim(); });
console.log(content);
```

=> firstNews is undefined !

I supposed I have to wait before getting the first value of the news list, but how can I do it properly ?

Comment: Perhaps the page in question just takes time (or waits for a specific event) to modify the DOM to populate `article.news`. `await` here doesn't awaits the element to exist, it only awaits for puppeteer to reply, and puppeteer replies with whatever it sees at that particular moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx to root, it seems adding a waitForSelector solved the problem :

```
await configPage.goto('http://....', {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'} );
await configPage.waitForSelector('article.news', {timeout: 5000});
let news = await configPage.$$("article.news");
let firstNews = news[0];
let content = await firstNews.$eval('div.news-body', s => { return s.textContent.trim(); });
console.log(content);
```